# Resize an image with float pixel values in python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

cv2.resize() does not accept float values and works only when pixel are `numpy.uint` . What is the best way for resizing an image/array that has float values?

Here is what works for uint. If img0 contains float, CV2 raises the following error.

```
img0 = numpy.array(input, dtype = numpy.uint)
img = cv2.cvtColor(img0, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
img_resized = cv2.resize(img, new_size)
```

> error: OpenCV(4.7.0)
> d:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.simd_helpers.hpp:94:
> error: (-2:Unspecified error) in function '__cdecl
> cv::impl::`anonymous-namespace'::CvtHelper<struct cv::impl::`anonymous
> namespace'::Set<1,-1,-1>,struct
> cv::impl::A0x73cf019b::Set<3,4,-1>,struct
> cv::impl::A0x73cf019b::Set<0,2,5>,2>::CvtHelper(const class
> cv::_InputArray &,const class cv::_OutputArray &,int)'
> Unsupported depth of input image:
> 'VDepth::contains(depth)'
> where
> 'depth' is 6 (CV_64F)

***Update/solution:***
CV2 supports float32, but not float64.

Comment: There are a couple of problems here.  The code you have above does not produce that error.  Instead, cvtColor complains because it cannot handle 32-bit uint pixels.  There are no image formats that use floats.  Are you trying to use OpenCV to resize an array that did not actually come from an image?

Comment: `scikit-image` module has `skimage.transform.resize`, which handles many numeric formats.

Comment: It's a processed image. Some math has been done and the output array is float.
I just realized I can for example multiply the array by 1e3 (to keep the required precision) and convert it to np.uint32 before feeding it to cv2.resize. However, that produced other issues downstream.

Comment: @Tim Roberts. TIFF supports floats. PFM supports floats

Comment: `float32` is supported by OpenCV. Try: `img0 = numpy.array(input, dtype=numpy.float32)`.  `skimage.transform.resize` supports `numpy.float64`.

Comment: @Rotem Thanks. My input was float64, but float32 works.